# How can I query Cassandra with GraphQL using a non-primary key column?

Tags: cassandra, graphql, nosql, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

I am using GraphQL for Cassandra database operation. The following search query work perfectly when filtering the column with partition key:

```
query oneUsers{
  users(value: { username:"username" }) {
    values {
      id
      name
      username
    }
  }
}
```

But getting following errors when trying to search other columns:

```
graphql: Exception while fetching data (/users) : org.apache.cassandra.stargate.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING
```

What is the best way to search columns in Cassandra using GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only retrieve records from Cassandra by specifying (a) the partition key, or (b) the primary key column(s).

If you would like to filter by non-primary key columns, you will need to [create an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-graphql-cql-first.html#_create_an_index) on the column. For example if you want to filter by `id`, create an index with:

```
mutation createIndexes {
  users: createIndex(
    keyspaceName:"myks",
    tableName:"users",
    columnName:"id",
    indexName:"id_idx"
  )
}
```

You should then be able to query by `id`.

For details and more examples, see [Developing with the Astra DB GraphQL API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-graphql-cql-first.html). Cheers!